# Process Builder Flow - Want to disable the error email alert temporarily

Tags: process-builder

I'm receiving the continuous emails with subject like "Error occured during Flow.." after I activated the flow. Is there any way to disable that email alerts temporarily for sometime? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are getting error, why don't you deactivate the flow.
Fix the errors and then reactivate.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is not possible to disable these alert emails from Salesforce, the best way to stop them would be to go back and correct the problems with the flow or process that is causing errors to be raised.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same thing:

The thing that I did is:

-make sure your criteria restricted enough to also work fine with the VR, triggers and etc you have in your system so the bug will not happen again.error in process builder, it's not something you want to ignore in any case.
What if in the future someone will add a VR or something else that will crash all the valid scenarios, even the one that works right now?

**IF after that explanation you still want it (which you not:)) another not recommended workaround is:**

The flow creator is the one who always receives emails for unhandled faults. You'll want to open the flow and resave it using a user with specific credentials so the emails will come to that email instead.
Update:
FROM  Summer 18 you can 
"Choose Who To Send Flow Fault emails and Process Builder Error Emails to"
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DvMGAA0